# What's the meaning of "Courtesy: [Name]" in an advertisement?

Tags: meaning, colons

What does the word "courtesy" mean with a ':'? Does it show the polite behaviour of the person named in the ad or does it show polite behaviour to him or is it a way to thank him?

> Food distribution among flood victims
>
> Courtesy: Mr James

Is the 2nd line thanking Mr James?

Comment: Make sure you **link to the source**  (or explain why you can't(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is probably a way of thanking him.

There is an idiom "(by) courtesy of" which means "with the permission of".

> This photo is provided courtesy of Mr James.

The form with a colon looks like a shortening of that. The meaning is clear. However, I've not seen courtesy used with that punctuation before.

Comment: and that he acknowledges that use of his material. A "Mr James allowed me to use this without charging me" kind of thing.

Answer (score 11):

Use of "Courtesy..." in a credit is not just a way of thanking someone, or stating that a resource was used with permission.  It's used specifically if the work being credited was provided free of charge.

From the *Chicago Manual of Style, 16th Edition*, p.128:

> 3.33 **Crediting material obtained free of charge.** For material that the author has obtained free and without restrictions on its use, the
> credit line may use the word *courtesy*.

Based on the short snippet in the question, I think the context may be that:

- "Food distribution among flood victims" is a caption on a photograph.
- Mr. James owns copyright to this photograph, but he allowed it to be used for free in this particular ad

Comment: *"Make sure you link to the source (or explain why you can't)."* - That's kinda what this is about, and that it's not 'fair use' or it'd have to say *CC BY-SA.* or w/e it is.

Answer (score 5):

[*courtesy of someone* is an idiom](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/courtesy-of)

> courtesy of someone
> idiom

> from someone as a gift:
> We got these gift certificates for nothing, courtesy of two local businesses.

Your example

> Courtesy: Mr James

is similar to saying *courtesy of Mr James*.  It is a way to thank Mr James.

Comment: 'Courtesy of' is not so much a way of thanking someone, as a way of simply acknowledging something that they did, or that they are the source of.

Answer (score 1):

It specifically means that this donation was made by Mr. James. But listing all the people who provided aid is a way of acknowledging and thanking all of them.